# VPS vs Real Hardware performance correlation

Tags: networking, performance, cloud, site-to-site-vpn, virtual-appliances

Assuming I have application running in a VPS and consuming 50% of assigned CPU resource. Will it correct to assume that on real hardware with same properties CPU usage will not be more than 50% running same application ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your app, cannot say it this way. Look over how CPU is used now. If it is using just calculation it should be more or less same, if it is waiting for some IO (storage, network) it can go better or worse.

Comment: Sure, I mean only CPU usage is troubling me. Memory is quite straightforward, but indeed would not measure IO

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if your question was tagged with site-to-site VPN for a reason, then there is one other factor: what the CPU actually supports.

x86-64 CPUs with baked in support for crypto primitives will generally use less CPU for VPN than a CPU (e.g. ARMv7) that lacks them.

Specifically for a VPN, this could be relevant, and worth checking into.